# How do I redirect stdout to a file when using subprocess.call in python?

Tags: python

I'm calling a python script (B) from another python script (A).

Using subprocess.call, how do I redirect the stdout of B to a file that specify?

I'm using python 2.6.1.

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess.call()` to execute another Python script? Wouldn't it be better to `import` it and call the appropriate functions?

Comment: Script B is a wrapper script that is calling A to which I want to send a list of arguments that I'm iterating through.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pass a file as the `stdout` parameter to `subprocess.call`:

```
with open('out-file.txt', 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call(['program'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: ...and this reminded me that I can also put `stderr=f`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen('lsblk -l|tee a.txt',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
(output,err)=p.communicate()
p_status=p.wait()
print output
```

Above code will write output of command to file a.txt

Comment: This one is useful if for some strange reason you need the subprocess to be in control of the file, not python (my case)

Comment: ...though that can, and should, still be done without `shell=True`; you can have two separate `Popen` objects, one for `lsblk` and a second one for `tee`, with the first's stdout connected to the second's stdin; the subprocess module docs show how to do so.