# Run console command with python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, xmllint

This code works fine directly in CLI:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Entities[contains(ExpirationDate, '2015')]' app/sftp/file.xml > test.xml
```

---

Now, I need to execute the same command but in Python environment. This is what I am trying:

```
def process_xml(path):
    call(["xmllint --xpath '//Entities[contains(ExpirationDate, '2015')]' app/sftp/file.xml > test.xml"])
```

This is the error, and I am running the file and command from the same location:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is `call()` function `subprocess.call()`?

Comment: @KevinGuan yes, from subprocess import call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect stdout to a file when using subprocess.call in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347004/how-do-i-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-when-using-subprocess-call-in-python)

Comment: Seems like you're using relative path, did you try absolute path like `/foo/bar/app/sftp/file.xml`?

Comment: The problem is more than that. It's around the usage of re-directing the output, i.e. `>`.

Comment: Also, `def process_xml(path):` what does this `path` arg do?

Comment: @idjaw But why does it raise `No such file or directory`?

Comment: @KevinGuan path will replace the app/sftp/file.xml, you can ignore it for now.

Comment: @idjaw Ah, seems like you're right :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use `os.system()` if you have nothing else to do with spawned process.

but, if you really want to use `subprocess.call` and stream redirection, you must use it like following:

```
with open('myfile', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.call(["xmllint", "--xpath", "//Entities[contains(ExpirationDate, '2015')]", "app/sftp/file.xml"], stdout=outfile)
```

please, notice that `subprocess.call` takes program name and its params as  a string list, maybe it's the problem