# pip freeze call with subprocess - No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pip

I am trying to write a `requirements.txt` file from within a Python script (Python 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04). Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347004/how-do-i-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-when-using-subprocess-call-in-python) I tried

```
import subprocess

with open("requirements.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.call(["pip freeze"], stdout=f)
```

but for a reason I don't know I get an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The folder where the script is run is writeable. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import subprocess

with open("requirements.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.call(["pip", "freeze"], stdout=f)
```

The "No such file" it means is "pip freeze". The example you cited didn't spell out how to pass command line arguments.