# Python - Piping in external program and store program output in file

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I want to write a python script that pipes a value of a variable (e.g. var = 5) into an external program. I want to store that output then in a .txt file.
Since I want to run a couple of these processes simultaneously I tried to do this using subprocess. But I failed.
Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edit your post and add the code ...

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable?rq=1)

Comment: Something like this? 
`from subprocess import check_output

# ls command
out = check_output(["ls", "-als"])

# open the empty file
logfilewriteout = open("/Users/youruser/Desktop/test.txt", 'w')

logfilewriteout.write(out)

logfilewriteout.close()`

Comment: I see several questions here: 1. How to pass `var`'s value to a subprocess (too broad: how do you want to pass it: as a command-line parameter `Popen(['command', str(var)], ...)`, or via subprocess' stdin e.g., as `var`'s text ascii representation `print(var, file=process.stdin)`, or using some other [IPC method](https://goo.gl/Ggw2PH)?) 2. How to [redirect subprocess' stdout to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9347004/4279) 3. How to [run multiple subprocesses in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279). Please, limit your question to one issue per question.