# Safely redirecting stdout to file from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, file, service, subprocess, stdout

I have a python service that runs some programs with `subprocess.Popen` and logs `stdout`/`stderr` to a file. It works nicely based upon the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347004/how-do-i-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-when-using-subprocess-call-in-python).

Since it is running as a service I want to be sure that the clean up is done correctly. The code has a structure similar to this:

```
while RunningService:
    try:
        command = "some command to run the program with arguments"

        with open('out-file.txt', 'a') as f_out:
            myProc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f_out, stderr=f_out)

        # some looping/waiting
        # ...
        # ...

        if breakCondition:
            break

    except Exception as e:
        # do some error logging for the caught exception
    finally:
        myProc.kill()
```

What I want to understand is what happens to the file handle `f_out` when we kill the process. When is the file closed? Would it be different if I created the Popen object in another function and returned it?

Comment: `f_out` is destroyed when you exit the `with open ... as f_out:` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that is wrong:

```
myProc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f_out, stderr=f_out)
```

You shouldn't use `f_out` for both `stdout` and `stderr` but rather:

```
myProc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f_out, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Then, be careful: if your process executes beyond the `with` block it may try to write into a closed file, and you'll get an exception.

The process has to be terminated from within the `with` block. Either kill it or wait for completion using `myProc.wait()` (blocking) or `myProc.poll() is not None` (non-blocking)

Comment: In this case, do `stdout` and `stderr` from the process still get written to the same file, just that `stderr` goes via `stdout`?

Comment: Same file it is. Try it for yourself.